# Magento 2 how to get best selling products

Tags: magento2

In magento 2 how can i get best selling products in block ?
And how can we find online visitor in Magento 2
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, please someone look into this... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check Below URL for Best Selling Products:

[Best way to display bestseller products](https://github.com/emizentech/magento2-best-seller)

For online customer You have to login in Magento Backend And follow the Below Steps

> Customer -> Now Online

Comment: Hello Emizen, sorry for late reply, actually i was on leave.  Magento2 not show correct best selling products at dashboard. They show best seller products from table "sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly" and this table not showing correct products. So did you fetch issue like this ? Or is there any setting for it ? Thanks

Comment: Actually i have to show best selling product from my module at admin panel. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.
Go to Report->Bestsellers then click on statistics link and then select "Refresh Lifetime Statistics" -> submit.